# Why pixel intensity from front face camera is always same as 0.5f (Frame.LightEstiamation.PixelIntesity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, arcore

I would like to create my own runtime light estimation but always when I call `Frame.LigthEstimation.PixelIntesity` this always same `0.5f`.
This result I've got only from front face (selfie) camera, for rear camera it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Which LightEstimationMode do you use?

PixelIntensity value is not meaningful when LightEstimationMode is not AmbientIntensity.

Comment: I use Ambient Intensity. With same options PixelIntensity works correctly when I use back camera. But with front face camera it's value always 0.5